# In Tensorflow, how to make a condition using indexes?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to create a tensor using a condition that is based on an index, in my case the minimum :

```
min_index = tf.argmin(tensor0)
new_tensor = tensor0*3 if index==min_index or tensor0*2
```

For example:

```
tensor0 = [4, 5, 1, 3]
armin(tensor0) = 2
condition = [False, False, True, False]  <-- How to make this one?
new_tensor = [4*2, 5*2, 1*3, 3*2]
```

I can't use `tf.equal` because my values are floating point and not integer like this simple example.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it! The "sparse_to_dense" function was what I was missing. Hope it helps someone:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tensor0 = tf.constant([4, 5, 1, 3], tf.float32)

argmin = tf.argmin(tensor0)

binary_mask = tf.cast(tf.sparse_to_dense(argmin, tensor0.shape, 1), tf.bool)

new_tensor = tf.where(binary_mask, tensor0*3, tensor0*2)
```